# How to Predict the sales of all the items, offered in all the countries

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting, python

I am working on a task to predict the sales of all the items offered in all the countries. The sales are aggregated on a daily and country level. Each Item has a history of past sales and prices for a given country. I want to predict the sales in upcoming n days.

Items have different sized histories, with some items being on sale for months, whereas others have been on sales for just a couple of weeks. Also note that during data analysis i noticed that price influenced the sales, when it is reduced customers bought more items of that type.

I just want to know the approach in predicting the sales. How should i approach in predicting the item wise sales and the effect of reducing the price. What should be my path to follow ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have daily data that includes period of time where no sales have occurred , the approach is called Intermittent Demand . If you have daily data (for each country ) that is generally non-zero then you should be looking at models that include anthropomorfic factors such as day-of-the-week, lead and lag effects of holiday indicators , week-of-the-month , day-of-the-month , monthly effects while incorporating user-specified predictor series like price or promotion effects AND any memory effects that might be present ALONG with possible trends and or level/step shifts.

An example of this can be found at  An example of this kind can be found at 
https://autobox.com/capable.pdf which I have helped to develop  starting at slide 49 which  may be of some help to you. Additionally search for daily data in SE and review some discussions.